# Loop through list in dictionary with dictionary values

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Given a dictionary as such

```
grouped_data = {"results":[{"id": 101, "name": toto}, {"id": 102, "name": cool}] }
```

It's a dict that has a list in which it has dictionaries

Hope I'm not confusing you ;), how can I get the *results* list and loop through each dictionary inside the list to compare the id between them with an if statement.

Comment: No need your help, already got it working thanks to real answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list:

```
resultList = grouped_data["results"]
```

Iterate through the list to get the dictionaries:

```
for dic in resultList:
    # use dic
```

To get values inside `dic`:

```
 for dic in resultList:
     for key,value in dic.iteritems():
         # use key and value
```

To access the `id` key, use:

```
 for dic in resultList:
     if dic['id'] == somevalue:
        # do_something
```

Comment: What are exactly key and value?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "*loop through each dictionary inside the list to compare the `id` between them with an if statement"*, this is one way to do it.
Example `if` statement below:

```
for i in grouped_data["results"]:
    if i['id'] > 101:
        print (i)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 102, 'name': 'cool'}
```

BTW: You have to convert `toto` and `cool` to `string` unless they are `variables` which you have declared in your code already.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'compare the id between them with an if statement'. Many ways to interpret it but here is something that you might use:

```
print (x for x in grouped_data['results'] if x['id'] > 101).next()
```

Output:

```
{'id': 102, 'name': 'cool'}
```